# Is there such a thing as "server sliding" (or similar), and if so, what is it?

Tags: radius, accounting

I am not a network engineer, but rather a translator, so I apologize in advance if this is a rather obvious question to some of you. Normally Google can answer my questions, but in this case I'm coming up blank. If I'm asking this in the wrong forum, please let me know.

The text is talking about RADIUS accounting functionality. It says that when there are many (more than 200) authenticated terminals, if a command is issued to forcibly clear the terminals, "sliding to the next RADIUS accounting server may occur" -- the original text literally says "RADIUS accounting server-slide".

I think I can basically understand what they are getting at in terms of meaning, but I would like to know whether this is the correct expression to use. I get the impression from my inability to find it simply by Googling that perhaps it's described differently in English.

Comment: I think I also know what they're saying, but you're right, that's not a great translation. A better site for you to try on would be [english.stackexchange.com](http://english.stackexchange.com) - if you're comfortable with your definition of the situation, they can provide you with a nice short phrase for it.

Comment: @mark do you really think that they're equipped to explain the technical meaning behind this?

Comment: @MarkM - no, but if you're after phrasing advice, they can help. If you ask for an alternate word for "sliding" with a basic explanation of what's happening (the service is being 'transferred'), they're pretty good at that. Plus most of them are from stack overflow.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion, @mark. Yes, I was thinking of asking at the English forum. But the document is aimed at experts, so like MarkM says, what I really need is the technical expression used by the experts, rather than simply an English layperson's phrase -- i.e. how would network engineers describe this phenomenon to each other?

Answer (score 1):

"**fallback**", or alternately "**failover**"

E.g. "**it may cause some clients to fallback to the next RADIUS accounting server.**"

Assuming the context is that the clients that would normally use this RADIUS accounting server end up using their next (less preferable) choice, that's usually called "fallback". "failover" also gets used, but more often in the context when all the clients would use the other server, not just some.